# Testing uptime of my personal server

Tags: php, http, curl

I made some code to test my personal servers uptime. It logs in to my router page and sees if it returns status 200. A cron job runs it every 5 minutes. Please let me know if I can make the code more efficient.

```
<?php
//Date
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date('m/d h:i:s a', time());

//Output
$myFile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/output.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");

//Count #
$count_file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/OK.txt";
$fil = fopen($count_file, r);
$dat = fread($fil, filesize($count_file)); 
fclose($fil);
$fil = fopen($count_file, w);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "MYURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USER:PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);


if($retcode==200){
    //fwrite($fh, "$date\tOK\n");
    $OK = $dat + 1;
    fwrite($fil, $OK);
    echo "$date\tOK\n";
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    fwrite($fh, "$date\t\tDOWN\n");
    echo "$date\tDOWN\n";
    fclose($fh);
}

//Count OK/DOWN
$read = file_get_contents($myFile);
$DOWN = preg_match_all("/DOWN/", $read, $matches) - 1;
$UP = 100*bcdiv($OK,$OK+$DOWN,4);

//Remove first line 
$read = file($myFile);
array_shift($read);
$server_up = "Server Uptime: " . $UP . "%\nOK: " . $OK . ", DOWN: " . $DOWN . "\n";
$read[0] = $server_up;
file_put_contents($myFile, $read);

?>
```

One thing I wanted to do was to somehow assign $OK to a variable and retrieve it the next time the page is loaded but I do not think PHP can do this so I saved it to an external file (OK.txt) and I read the value every time and increment it every time my site returns 200.

Here is a sample output.txt file:

> ```
> Server Uptime: 92.5%
> OK: 37, DOWN: 3
> 09/30 06:48:28 pm DOWN
> 09/30 06:48:28 pm DOWN
> 09/30 06:48:28 pm DOWN
> ```

Comment: Why do you use fopen, fread in the first part of the code, then file_get_contents in the 2nd part? to me it would be simpler to use file_get_contents and file_put_contents, but I thought I would check incase you have a specific reason

Comment: I used fopen to use string operations on fwrite and i used file_get_contents so I could used preg_match_all to count occurences of "Down"

Comment: short of breaking it into functions/methods (which is probably overkill), the code looks fine, its easy to read and understand, not sure it can be improved much

Comment: Put all of the curl options in an associative array, put it at the top of your script, and call `curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);`. One function call, all options are set + all options can be maintained more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**

You should choose longer variable names. For example, with names as `$fil` and `$fh` it's hard to remember which one was which. You could name them `$output` and `$count`.

But all other names should be expressive as well. `$dat` might be `$uptime_count`, and `$myFile` -> `$output_file_name`, `$fh` -> `$output_file`, `$count_file` -> `$count_file_name` (it't just a string, not a file), `$ch` -> `$curl`, etc.

For some names it's obviously more important than for others, but good naming is always an improvement.

**Variable Scoping**

`$fh` is only used once, far away from where it was defined, inside the `else` statement. I would move the opening code here, so you don't have to think about `$fh` outside the `else`.

It's closed in the `if` as well, but that is unnecessary. Don't open up the file if you don't plan on writing to it.

**Functions**

The code isn't all that long, but I would still extract some functionality to its own function. Especially the counting of previous up and down times, and maybe the connecting to the server.